# Having problems understanding the result mixing "For loops" and "array" (beginner)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm currently studying javascript and I don't understand the result based on a specific condition. Thanks for you patience with newbies like myself ;)

In the following case, I don't understand why the last line "blue" is displayed since the condition is "show only when counter > 0".

```
var table = ['blue','yellow','orange','red'];
for (var counter = table.length ; counter > 0 ; counter--)
{
document.write(table[counter-1] + "<br>")
}
```

Another way to see the result would be :

```
var table = ['blue','yellow','orange','red'];
document.write(table[table.length-1] + '<br>'); // result: table[3] "red"
document.write(table[table.length-2] + '<br>'); // result: table[2] "orange"
document.write(table[table.length-3] + '<br>'); // result: table[1] "yellow"
document.write(table[table.length-4] + '<br>'); // result: table[0] "blue" = should not be displayed if we have the condition 'counter > 0'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are aware that you are subtracting `1` from `counter` when accessing the Array?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware because if you don't do that, the first value displayed will be "undefined" (table [4]).

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I'll test them later. What you have to be aware is that I got this way from a book I'm learning (JS Jquery missing manual). That's why I find it wierd and I'm asking the question.
I'm posting on this website for the first time. Thx to the guy who gave a lower rating to my question. Sorry, it might be a dumb question but I'm currently at the dumb level ;) Just trying to understand the logic of the book...

Comment: Try to keep in mind that array indexes are 0 based, whereas length values aren't. Start such a loop at `var i = arr.length - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using -

```
var table = ['blue','yellow','orange','red'];
for (var counter = table.length ; counter > 0 ; counter--)
{
    document.write(table[counter-1] + "<br>") //when table has 4 item, counter = 1, counter > 0, table[counter - 1] = table[0]
}
```

In other words, your code perfectly prints all. If you wish to skip the last one do this -

```
var table = ['blue','yellow','orange','red'];
for (var counter = table.length - 1; counter > 0 ; counter--)
{
    document.write(table[counter] + "<br>")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmud for taking the time adding the code ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the below line:

`document.write(table[counter-1] + "<br>")`, you are decrementing the counter by 1. It will not validate the condition here.

Use this `counter - 1 > 0`

Answer (score 0):

It is because inside your loop, you are using `table[counter-1]`.
Counter never reaches `0` but you take away 1 from it, which makes it access the zero'th element of `table`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript arrays are initiate in index 0. In your conditional you do loop from length array until 1 "counter >0" but when you print the array item you get counter-1, if counter is equal 1 you will get array index 0.